# htmlunit iteration getPage

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit to web-scrape a page.

I am doing a table iteration with many rows (tr) where each row has one link that I want access to get data. This final page is a real time updated.

In the first iteration (1) I call a getPage() method and everything it's ok.
But in the next iterations (1....N) I want to reduce time and not call again the getPage() but only to access to the first HtmlPage object created and get new data (updated). My approach is to keep the pages always accessible and save time.

Anyone already had this approach?

Comment: Sorry but i did not get your point but i like to help you with this. Please open an issue for HtmlUnit and we can discuss this in more detail.

Comment: I would first extract all links (List of URL) and than follow then in a loop (getPage(URL)). What exactly is your problem?